# Completed 500 Internal Server Error on user signup with Devise on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, devise

I have copied a project I've done in Rails into another folder. When I want to create/register a new user using the Devise gem, it works locally on my computer. However, when I want to do the same on Heroku, the Heroku logs give me these errors (500 Internal Server Error and NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass) for the user):

```
2017-10-18T09:13:44.841868+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-10-18T09:13:44.841788 #4] DEBUG -- : [8944a6a0-36d4-4f3a-b4e2-967d5273ae3c]    (1.2ms)  ROLLBACK
2017-10-18T09:13:44.844378+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-10-18T09:13:44.844294 #4]  INFO -- : [8944a6a0-36d4-4f3a-b4e2-967d5273ae3c] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1109ms (ActiveRecord: 122.8ms)
2017-10-18T09:13:44.845813+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-10-18T09:13:44.845733 #4] FATAL -- : [8944a6a0-36d4-4f3a-b4e2-967d5273ae3c]   
2017-10-18T09:13:44.845955+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-10-18T09:13:44.845867 #4] FATAL -- : [8944a6a0-36d4-4f3a-b4e2-967d5273ae3c] NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
2017-10-18T09:13:44.846016+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-10-18T09:13:44.845935 #4] FATAL -- : [8944a6a0-36d4-4f3a-b4e2-967d5273ae3c]   
2017-10-18T09:13:44.846141+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-10-18T09:13:44.846063 #4] FATAL -- : [8944a6a0-36d4-4f3a-b4e2-967d5273ae3c] app/models/user.rb:150:in `set_pinned_posts'
2017-10-18T09:13:44.846302+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-10-18T09:13:44.846146 #4] FATAL -- : [8944a6a0-36d4-4f3a-b4e2-967d5273ae3c] app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:3:in `create'
```

The user table exists, however I cannot create a user on Heroku.

**What I've done so far:**

- migrating the database with `heroku run rails db:migrate`
- restarting the heroku server `heroku restart -a appname`
- I'm also using AWS S3 by Amazon for the Paperclip gem and in this project I use the same keys which I also use for two other projects. The other two projects work just fine. (e.g. the keys are: AWS Access Key, AWS Region, AWS Secret Access Key, Secret Key Base). Could that be the problem?
- Deleted the version number of the pg gem in my gemfile and bundle installed again
- Similar questions on Stackoverflow showed that the problem could lie in the email confirmation after the registration. However, I did not activate email confirmation on Devise.

**The User model method in the error message:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :set_pinned_posts

  ...

  def set_pinned_posts
    Fpost.where(pinned: true).all.each do |post|
      self.randomized_fposts.where(fpost_id: post.id).each do |post|
        post.set_faketime_for_pinnedposts
      end
    end

    first = Fpost.where(pinned: true).first
    last = Fpost.where(pinned: true).last

    self.randomized_fposts.where(fpost_id: first.id).update_all(fake_time: 1.days.ago)
    self.randomized_fposts.where(fpost_id: last.id).update_all(fake_time: 30.days.ago)
  end
end
```

Comment: `app/models/user.rb:150:in  set_pinned_posts`
That's where your error is happening.  Maybe post your model code so we can help?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the method (in this method I set "fake posts" to pinned and change their posting time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are this is the issue:

```
first = Fpost.where(pinned: true).first
last = Fpost.where(pinned: true).last
```

with first = Fpost.where(pinned: true) returning nil. (Do you have any Fpost objects connected to the user at this stage?)

This would explain your error 'NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):' being thrown by this:

```
.... .where(fpost_id: first.id) ...
```

as id is being called on nil.

Comment: Oh my god, that was it, thank you very much. I've forgotten to seed my "Fposts", therefore there were no FPosts.`heroku run rake db:seed` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run rake db:migrate? You can also run migrations via web dashboard. Sometimes rails db:migrate does not work in heroku. And also did you try to create a new user via console?